# How to clone select2 v4 Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am attempting to do an AJAX call with the Select2 ver4 jquery plugin and Using Loading remote data of Select2 sample page
I am trying to clone a select which contains select2 tool.
But select2 dropdown disabled when cloning.

HTML CODE

```
<tr>
<td>
<select class="js-example-data-ajax" id="sel1">
</select>
<button type="button" class="addline">Add Line</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

jQuery CODE

```
     $.fn.select2.amd.require(
    ["select2/core", "select2/utils", "select2/compat/matcher"],
    function (Select2, Utils, oldMatcher) {

  var $ajax = $(".js-example-data-ajax");

  function formatRepo (repo) {
    if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

    var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
    '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
    '<img src="' + repo.owner.avatar_url + '" style="max-width: 100%" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div clas="col-sm-10">' +
    '<div class="clearfix">' +
    '<div class="col-sm-6">' + repo.full_name + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> ' + repo.forks_count + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> ' + repo.stargazers_count + '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    if (repo.description) {
      markup += '<div>' + repo.description + '</div>';
    }

    markup += '</div></div>';

    return markup;
  }

  function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.full_name || repo.text;
  }

  $ajax.select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term // search term
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, params) {
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '.addline', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $lastTr = $tr.closest('table').find('tr:last');

    $lastTr.find('.js-example-data-ajax').select2('destroy');

    var $clone = $lastTr.clone();

    $clone.find('td').each(function() {
        var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
        var id = el.attr('id') || null;
        if (id) {
            var i = id.substr(id.length - 1);
            var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length - 1));
            el.attr('id', prefix + (+i + 1));
            el.attr('name', prefix + (+i + 1));
        }
    });
    $tr.closest('tbody').append($clone);
    $lastTr.find('.js-example-data-ajax').select2();
    $clone.find('.js-example-data-ajax').select2();
});
$('.js-example-data-ajax').select2();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the clone, you have to run the very same select2 arguments for it (in addition to your original one that you've destroyed). You can either declare the arguments as a global variable and then use it in the two places (which is better practice), or to include them again, which for the sake of optimized answer you can see below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addline', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $lastTr = $tr.closest('table').find('tr:last');

    $lastTr.find('.js-example-data-ajax').select2('destroy');

    var $clone = $lastTr.clone();

    $clone.find('td').each(function() {
        var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
        var id = el.attr('id') || null;
        if (id) {
            var i = id.substr(id.length - 1);
            var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length - 1));
            el.attr('id', prefix + (+i + 1));
            el.attr('name', prefix + (+i + 1));
        }
    });
    $tr.closest('tbody').append($clone);

    // ADDED:
    $(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term // search term
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
          // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
          // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
          // scrolling can be used
          params.page = params.page || 1;

          return {
            results: data
          };
        },
        cache: true
      },
      escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
      minimumInputLength: 1,
    });

    // BAD PRACTICE: Make the entire { ajax: ...} block as a global variable,
    // then use it both here and on your original $ajax.select2(...) call.

});
```

Comment: thank you. I take a mistake...I was corrected the name of the class , but it does not work

Comment: Your edited code seems to be working just fine for me. Can you elaborate what youdo  mean by _"does not work"_, and possibly create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to play with?

Comment: Really? First select element is no problem, but The duplicated element don't work. This element is not connected to json. This element display always"no Result"  https://jsfiddle.net/uc1b74L3/

Comment: You've changed your entire code since your original question. See my new edited answer.

Comment: Great! Your code is excellent work that I hope . Motion like a charm! Thank you for your helping!

Comment: Please Help again. Now I want get element's value of select and pass next div(class=hint). but Duplicated element(hint) don't get a value. Please see my new edited question(ADD).

Comment: @Hiro if you have a new question, you should not edit the current one - it'll only confuse anyone who'll come here in the future. Follow-up questions should be created as [new questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: thank you for your advice! I have a new question and edit new one!

Comment: I make a new question! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442348/select2-v4-clone-dont-pass-the-data) @uri2x Thank you for your helping!